# _userManager.CreateAsync not working. No exception returned and finishes as HTTP error 500

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-5.0

I implemented Identity on a ASP .Net Core 5 Web Application. I already created and ran the proper database migrations. However, when I run the application and I try to register a new account

[image]

[image]

It nevers finishes the CreateAsync and at the end it's shown a blank page showing Http Error 500

Comment: Can you show your code without an image?

Comment: I must to mention the database I'm using is a SQL Server database running on a Docker container. The SQL Server runs perfectly I got access to it using SSMS. Basically the problem happens when I try to execute the CreateAsync method in the UserManager object. This process never ends and don't return any exception, the webpage is just redirected to an error page showing Http Error 500

Comment: I tried also creating a new Web MVC Application, selecting the same authentication type (Individual accounts) but not selecting the Docker support for it. I scaffolded the Identity pages required for user login and registration and the part of _userManager.CreateAsync worked fine. Then, I added Docker support to the project and tested again and then I found _userManager.CreateAsync failed just like in the original project. I think this problem is related to Docker in any form. My database is SQL Server and this is running in a separate Docker image and I have access to it by using SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like after a lot of fails, I finally found a solution.

You need to change the Connection String in appsettings.json

From

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost,1433;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=YourPassword;",
```

To

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,1433;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=YourPassword;",
```

I also applied the solution mentioned in this link:

https://tutexchange.com/how-to-customise-asp-net-core-identity/

After doing both parts, I am now able to register an user account.